# Explicit $H^2(K, \mu) = Q/Z$?

Tags: class-field-theory, galois-cohomology, local-fields

In the development of local class field theory, a very fundamental theorem is that, for every local field $K$ of characteristic zero,

$H^2(K, \mu) \cong \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$. $(*)$

Neukirch et al. in *Cohomology of Number Fields* prove $(*)$ in an indirect way involving the existence of a "dualizing module." I'd like to know if there's an explicit description of the isomorphism $(*)$ (in either direction). In particular, if $L/K$ is a finite extension, then the restriction and corestriction maps $H^2(K, \mu) \to H^2(L, \mu) \to H^2(K, \mu)$ presumably correspond to multiplication by two integers whose product is $[L : K] = n$. What are those integers?

Comment: See Ch. XIII, section 3, Proposition 7 of Serre's *Local Fields* and the discussion preceding it (and in general read that book for a nice treatment of local class field theory, treating all local fields -- of all characteristics -- on equal footing; e.g. he discusses with proof the concrete meaning in terms of central simple algebras). Serre's article on local class field theory in the book *Algebraic Number Theory* edited by Cassels and Frohlich is also very illuminating.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. Ch. XIII, section 3 indeed contained the material I needed.